# Problems upgrading rsync in Redhat

Tags: bash, centos, upgrade, rsync

I have installed **rsync version 3.0.6  protocol version 30** and want to upgrade to version 3.1.1 or 3.1.2.

If I try to install using yum I get that is already installed latest version

```
# yum -y install rsync
Package rsync-3.0.6-12.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I've tried download the versions rsync-3.1.1.tar and rsync-3.1.2.tar to install manually sending

```
./configure
make install
```

I don't see any visible error when sending both commands above, but when I check the **rsync --version** again, the version still is 3.0.6.

What I'm doing wrong?

The linux version below:

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Aug 13 22:55:16 UTC 2015
# cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> make install
> ```

Doing make install probably installed your new version into some different paths or partially overwrote your previous installation. It is usually not a good idea to do this. Better way of is checking at least what configure options are used by redhat.

Anyway, from the `make install` log, you should see the paths where was your new rsync installed.

Comment: Hello Jakuje, thanks for answer. It seems that after trying to install again (more than 3 times hehe) rsync, this time shows new version.